# How to add multiple dependencies using angular.module and Angular Material

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, module, angular-material

I'm having an issue with Angular Material where my forms/inputs and buttons don't show up.
I'm guessing it's because I havent added ngMaterial as a dependency. When I do, it breaks my code.

this is my original app.js file:

```js
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute',])

.config( [
    '$compileProvider',
    function( $compileProvider ) {
        var currentImgSrcSanitizationWhitelist = $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist();
        var newImgSrcSanitizationWhiteList = currentImgSrcSanitizationWhitelist.toString().slice(0,-1)
        + '|chrome-extension:'
        +currentImgSrcSanitizationWhitelist.toString().slice(-1);

        console.log("Changing imgSrcSanitizationWhiteList from "+currentImgSrcSanitizationWhitelist+" to "+newImgSrcSanitizationWhiteList);
        $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(newImgSrcSanitizationWhiteList);
    }
])

.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'templates/home.html', 
      controller: 'MainCtrl'
    })
    .when('/settings', {
      templateUrl: 'templates/settings.html',
      controller: 'SettingsCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
})





 .provider("Weather", function () {
    var apiKey = "";
 
    this.setApiKey = function (key) {
      if (key) {
        this.apiKey = key;
      }
    };
 
    this.getUrl = function (type, ext) {
      return "http://api.wunderground.com/api/" + this.apiKey + "/" + type +
             "/q/" + ext + ".json";
    };





      this.$get = function ($q, $http) {
      var self = this;
      return {
        getWeatherForecast: function (city) {
          var d = $q.defer();
 
          $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: self.getUrl("forecast", city),
            cache: true
          }).success(function (data) {
            // forecasts are nested inside forecast.simpleforecast
            // console.log(data);
            d.resolve(data.forecast.simpleforecast);
          }).error(function (error) {
            d.reject(error);
          });
 
          return d.promise;
        }
      };
    };
  })







.config(function(WeatherProvider) {
  WeatherProvider.setApiKey('7b78fc434225f02f');
})



.controller('MainCtrl',
 function($scope, $timeout, Weather){

 //build date object
 $scope.date = {};
 // Update function
 var updateTime = function() {
  $scope.date.raw = new Date();
  $timeout(updateTime, 1000);
 }

 // Kick off the update function
 updateTime();


     $scope.weather = {};
 
    Weather.getWeatherForecast("IL/Chicago")
      .then(function (data) {
        $scope.weather.forecast = data;
      });



});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html data-ng-app="myApp" data-ng-csp="">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Weathim</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/angular-material.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/teal-theme.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rajdhani|Dosis:400,700|Raleway:400,100,300|Advent+Pro' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl" md-theme="teal">
    <md-toolbar flex="100" flex-order="1">
      <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
        <h2>
          <span>{{ date.raw | date:'EEEE MMMM yyyy' }}</span>
        </h2>
        <span flex></span>
        <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="Settings">
          <md-icon><img src="imgs/settings.png"></md-icon>
        </md-button>
      
      </div>
    </md-toolbar>
      <div class="container">
  <md-content layout="row" layout-align="center">
    <div id="datetime">
      <div class="time">{{ date.raw | date:'hh:mm' }}</div><div class="sec">{{ date.raw | date:'ss' }}</div>
      <div class="day"></div>
    </div>
  </md-content>
  <div layout="row" layout-sm="column">
    <md-content class="bg1" ng-repeat="day in weather.forecast.forecastday" id="forecast">
      <div ng-class="{today: $index == 0}">
        <div flex="25">
          <md-toolbar class="md-warn">
            <div class="md-toolbar-tools" layout-align="center">
              <h2 class="md-flex" ng-if="$index == 0">Now</h2>
              <h2 class="md-flex" ng-if="$index != 0">{{ day.date.weekday }}</h2>
            </div>
          </md-toolbar>
          <div class="infocontent" layout layout-align="center">
            <img class="{{ day.icon }}" ng-src="imgs/{{ day.icon }}.png"/>
          </div>
          <div layout="row">
              <div flex class="low">
                Low: <span class="temp" layout layout-align="center">{{ day.low.fahrenheit }}</span>
              </div>
              <div flex class="high">
                High: <span class="temp" layout layout-align="center">{{ day.high.fahrenheit }}</span>
              </div>
          </div>

          <md-toolbar class="md-warn border">
            <div class="md-toolbar-tools" layout-align="center">
              <h2 class="md-flex">{{ day.conditions }}</h2>
            </div>
          </md-toolbar>


        </div>
      </div>
    </md-content>
  </div>

  <md-content md-theme="docs-dark" layout-padding layout="row" layout-sm="column">
 <input ng-model="" placeholder="Placeholder text"><md-button class="md-raised md-primary">Primary</md-button>
  </md-content>
</div>
    <script src="./js/vendor/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/vendor/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/vendor/angular-material.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/vendor/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

i attempted to add multiple dependencies but it just broke my code:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute', 
  'ngMaterial'
  ]).config(function($mdThemingProvider) {
  $mdThemingProvider.theme('teal')
    .primaryPalette('teal')
    .accentPalette('orange');
})

.config( [
    '$compileProvider',
    function( $compileProvider ) {
        var currentImgSrcSanitizationWhitelist = $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist();
        var newImgSrcSanitizationWhiteList = currentImgSrcSanitizationWhitelist.toString().slice(0,-1)
        + '|chrome-extension:'
        +currentImgSrcSanitizationWhitelist.toString().slice(-1);

        console.log("Changing imgSrcSanitizationWhiteList from "+currentImgSrcSanitizationWhitelist+" to "+newImgSrcSanitizationWhiteList);
        $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(newImgSrcSanitizationWhiteList);
    }
])

.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'templates/home.html', 
      controller: 'MainCtrl'
    })
    .when('/settings', {
      templateUrl: 'templates/settings.html',
      controller: 'SettingsCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
})





 .provider("Weather", function () {
    var apiKey = "";
 
    this.setApiKey = function (key) {
      if (key) {
        this.apiKey = key;
      }
    };
 
    this.getUrl = function (type, ext) {
      return "http://api.wunderground.com/api/" + this.apiKey + "/" + type +
             "/q/" + ext + ".json";
    };





      this.$get = function ($q, $http) {
      var self = this;
      return {
        getWeatherForecast: function (city) {
          var d = $q.defer();
 
          $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: self.getUrl("forecast", city),
            cache: true
          }).success(function (data) {
            // forecasts are nested inside forecast.simpleforecast
            // console.log(data);
            d.resolve(data.forecast.simpleforecast);
          }).error(function (error) {
            d.reject(error);
          });
 
          return d.promise;
        }
      };
    };
  })







.config(function(WeatherProvider) {
  WeatherProvider.setApiKey('7b78fc434225f02f');
})



.controller('MainCtrl',
 function($scope, $timeout, Weather){

 //build date object
 $scope.date = {};
 // Update function
 var updateTime = function() {
  $scope.date.raw = new Date();
  $timeout(updateTime, 1000);
 }

 // Kick off the update function
 updateTime();


     $scope.weather = {};
 
    Weather.getWeatherForecast("IL/Chicago")
      .then(function (data) {
        $scope.weather.forecast = data;
      });



});
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: First of all you are linking angular.min.js twice, one at the beginning and one at the end. Also put the link to angular-material in last-place, after angular-animate